# subtract each row from all other rows and view as matrix in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have df like this:

```
id   date
1    01-02-2013
2    01-06-2013
3    05-31-2013
4    07-06-2013
```

and I want to build a matrix that shows me for each id, the time elapsed between the specific id to all others ( in days). i.e. something like this:

```
   1  2  3    4
1  0  4 -149  -185
2  4  0  -145  -181
....
```

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df.set_index('id', inplace=True)
```

You can just subtract all the values of date column from each value in it, End result is:

```py
df['date'].apply(lambda x:x-df['date'])
id        1        2         3         4
id                                      
1    0 days  -4 days -149 days -185 days
2    4 days   0 days -145 days -181 days
3  149 days 145 days    0 days  -36 days
4  185 days 181 days   36 days    0 days
```

And if you don't want to display `days` string, you can use `dt.days` attribute to access the number of days:

```py
df['date'].apply(lambda x:x-df['date']).apply(lambda x: x.dt.days)
id    1    2    3    4
id                    
1     0   -4 -149 -185
2     4    0 -145 -181
3   149  145    0  -36
4   185  181   36    0
```

You can finally use `.values` attribute if you want to get numpy array:

```py
df['date'].apply(lambda x:x-df['date']).apply(lambda x: x.dt.days).values

array([[   0,   -4, -149, -185],
       [   4,    0, -145, -181],
       [ 149,  145,    0,  -36],
       [ 185,  181,   36,    0]], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: This is a very useful answer.

Comment: thank you so much.. easier than I thought. How could I remove the word "days" from the all df ? I tried with dt.days but not working

Comment: @nay, the answer is already there, make sure the value on which you are trying to use `dt.days` is timedelta type, else, it won't work; timedelta is the difference between two datetime type data

Comment: You have unlocked [upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up#:~:text=When%20you%20vote%20up%2C%20you,sorted%20by%20number%20of%20votes.&text=Upvotes%20on%20a%20question%20give,give%20the%20answerer%20%2B10%20reputation.) privilege now, you can upvote questions and answers that are helpful to you,. You can take a look at [How can I upvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments)

Answer (score 0):

With numpy's broadcasting<sup>*</sup>:

```
values = df.date.to_numpy()
diff = (values[:, np.newaxis] - values).astype("timedelta64[D]")
```

to get

```
>>> diff

array([[   0,   -4, -149, -185],
       [   4,    0, -145, -181],
       [ 149,  145,    0,  -36],
       [ 185,  181,   36,    0]], dtype="timedelta64[D]")
```

Converting back to a dataframe:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(diff, index=df.id, columns=df.id)

id        1        2         3         4
id
1    0 days  -4 days -149 days -185 days
2    4 days   0 days -145 days -181 days
3  149 days 145 days    0 days  -36 days
4  185 days 181 days   36 days    0 days
```

<sup>*</sup>: you can see the last row in [this image](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/figures/02.05-broadcasting.png)